# Passing Value from OnTriggerEnter function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to pass on a value from OnTriggerEnter function for a class to another class.I already set the value that I want to pass to global variable.This is how I do :

```
public GameObject go;
public bool isSomething;    
public static AClass instance;

public void Start()
{
   instance=this;
}    

public void OnTriggerEnter(Collision other)
{
   if(go.tag=="Something")
   {
     isSomething=true;
   }
}
```

The problem is at another class,I call `isSomething` from `AClass` and I run the Unity,it give me NullExceptionReference when I pass through a game object.This is the another class code :

```
private AClass aclass;
public void Start()
{
  aclass=AClass.instance;
}

public void Update()
{
  Debug.Log(aclass.isSomething); //<-----------------This give Null Exception Reference
}
```

I want to get a value just after I pass a collider trigger and not before passing a collider trigger.I don't know is this a dumb question but I hope someone can give me some idea.Thanks. :)

Comment: is Aclass a static class

Comment: Not. is just public class AClass,but to get the component inside that class,I code it public static AClass instance inside that class.

Comment: why not just make your class static or its methods that you want to use static

Answer (score 2):

Try assigning the instance in the Awake function:

```
public void Awake()
{
   instance = this;
}
```

There's no guarantee that the Start() function of one object happens before or after that of another object unless you explicitly set the execution order.

Comment: Yup,I have tried this one also.I forgot to mention about that.

Comment: @edwardau LearnCocos2D is right, you should do that kind of assignment in the `Awake` not the `Start`. Remember, `Awake` happens before `Start`.

Answer (score 0):

This code is wrong.

```
public void OnTriggerEnter(Collision other)
{
   if(go.tag=="Something")
   {
     isSomething=true;
   }
}
```

**Solution**

```
public void OnTriggerEnter(Collision other)
{ 
   if(other.tag == "Something")
     isSomething=true;
}
```